# US: How should I use feet/yards/miles?

Tags: internationalisation, localization

I'm trying to localise an app for the US. The app shows a list of places with distances that are relatively close, so either walkable less than a 10 minute drive away. Currently if the distance is over 1km then I show the distance in metres, so the list looks like this:

- 100m away
- 1.1 km away

What do you think makes sense for the US? 
Should I switch down to yards or feet or both and where does it make sense to make the switch? I know that it's common in the US to use a quarter mile as a distance, so maybe it makes more sense just to use miles that can be a fraction, so 0.2 mi.

US people, please help me out!

Comment: I'd avoid decimal places with the Imperial System. Whilst a "quarter mile" might be well understood, 0.25mi would probably confuse most people used to that system of measurement. Furthermore, the units of measure most people use is a small subset of the available Imperial units (few would know what a `chain` or `furlong` is).

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but as a US citizen, 0.25 miles is not at all confusing.

Comment: I've noticed that compared to the UK, yards aren't used much in the US.  We'd say 100 yards, but Americans would be more likely to say 300 feet.  So I'd forget about yards which may simplify things a little.

Comment: As someone who is *not* from the US but has used a number of apps which were created there, and then localised, I have often noticed that the concept of 'nearby' appears to be different also. For example they would recommend a restaurant as being 'nearby' if it was 10km or more away through the city, when to me 'nearby' means within walking distance or maximum 2-3km if I'm driving. Ymmv depending on the application, but this could be useful in expanding the circle in some locales.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann, I'm with max, .25 miles isn't confusing at all and is something that we see consistently in our navigation systems, fitness apps and on google maps. Not to mention what we use in general conversation.

Comment: I'd say those of us who are comfortable using GPS systems would be comfortable with .2 miles (or .3 miles), but if your audience is not as comfortable with technology, get down to 1/4 mile and then use feet once you get to 1,000 feet.  In all honesty, most of us round to a quarter mile if below one mile anyway, and then we have 1 mile, 1 1/2 mile, 2 miles, and then we are probably at whole miles from there on out (3 1/2 miles might as well be 3 or 4 miles, but 2 1/2 miles may work).

Comment: Also consider what your actual precision is. For many geolocation services feet don't make a ton of sense. .1 of a mile is about as precise as the data you have will be anyway.

Comment: The US is a very large, diverse country. For all of those people saying they never use "yards", there are other native-born US people like me, who would find "yards" more familiar than "feet". As in, "that tree over there, the one about 50 yards away". Maybe in my region ((American) football country) we use "feet" for very short distances, "yards" for distances up to about 100 yards, and fractions of a mile for anything over... 3 feet, 10 feet, 20 yards, 80 yards, 100 yards, 1/4 mile, 1/2 mile, ...

Comment: I recommend 100-0.2 miles, then switching to feet. It' covers almost everything.

Comment: @Wildcard A single app certainly cannot turn the tides all by itself, so proper localization has to byte that sour apple anyway, but long-term, the metric system would be the better choice UX-wise.

Comment: As an American the only case I can think of with a distance expressed in yards is in reference to football--and since the field is 100 **yards** it's the logical unit.  Beyond that, yards are a measurement of size, not distance.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, what on earth do you mean by that?  *"yards are a measurement of size, not distance."*  A yard is 3 feet.  36 inches.  91.44 centimeters.

Comment: @Wildcard I'm talking about how I've seen people use them.  Football fields are 100 yards long.  Carpet is generally sold by the square yard.  Fabric is usually sold by the yard.  In other words, the size of something, not how far away it is.

Comment: This does not directly answer the question but it may be an interesting side note, in the UK we used metres for shorter distances and miles for longer distances.

Comment: Distances in the US are measured in **rods**. I learned this important fact from watching the Simpsons. Abe's car gets 40 rods to the hogshead, and that's the way he likes it. Americans are not comfortable with stops in numbers so for accuracy you should express distances fully. For example: *"Denver is 37 nautical miles, 3 furlongs 2 rods 7 and seventeen thirty-secondths of an inch and a couple of thou from here."*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're dealing with geographical distances, just use miles. We never think of towns being X feet or yards away from each other.

Our street signs (and mapping apps, etc.) show decimals, so that's a good way to handle fractional miles. Even under a mile we're used to seeing distances like 0.2 miles. (One decimal place is usually enough.) Even when things are just a short distance from each other, I'd still use decimal miles. Just round the number to the nearest 0.1.

[Edit: It's not uncommon to see road signs that use fractions. My memory's been influenced by Google Maps.]

(Set your Google Maps to US measures and see what it does.)

Fractional distances like "a quarter mile" are used more conversationally: "She lives a half mile from me." But you don't see that usage on highway signs.

Comment: I often see fractional distances on highway signs in the U.S. 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4 miles are all very common where I am. See something like: http://i.imgur.com/46Oa90U.jpg . Indeed, seeing "38th Street Exit  0.2 Miles" would look very out of place to me.

Comment: Just want to point out that [Google Maps uses feet for distances less than 0.1 miles](http://i.imgur.com/DxjNatn.png), but otherwise behaves as you described.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I recall now seeing those fractional signs on highways. I'll update my answer. For an app, though, I think decimals would be the way to go.

Comment: For the most part I agree, but I think feet is fine to use for precise directions (think turn-by-turn GPS navigation) in amounts less than 500 or so. Otherwise, miles all the way. Most U.S. cities have a standardized block size as well (a Chicago block is 1/8 mile) so most people have a good idea of what 0.2 miles roughly is in terms of some physical like a block.

Comment: I've even seen “1/3 mile” sometimes.

Comment: "The app shows a list of places with distances that are relatively close, so either walkable less than a 10 minute drive away." Town being X feet is not proper analogy.

Comment: There are a lot of signs that say "in 1000 feet" or something like that.

Comment: Google Maps uses "1000 feet" sometimes, and it screwed me up a lot until I trained myself to recognize it—initially, I heard "feet" and assumed we were talking about the next turn, maybe the one after that, but of course a thousand feet is nearly a quarter mile. I say avoid it altogether!

Comment: And "¾ mile," "½ mile," "¼ mile," are extremely common on highway signs where I am (I make regular trips between NYC and DC). There's even a "⅕ mile" near me. I don't see decimals on signs very often at all.

Comment: The MUTCD [legal standard on US traffic signs] doesn't give a specific guideline on when to use feet or miles, but it contains no examples below 1/4 mile [and does specifically say not to use decimals] or above 1500 feet. Mapping applications do tend to use decimal miles and give more precision than road signs (of course, the highway department can put the sign where they want to make "1000 feet" or "1/4 mile" accurate, the app has to use the GPS location of your car)

Answer (score 9):

I have noticed a soft crossover from mi to feet on street signs around 1000ft (0.19)  I say its a soft crossover, because you will see things like 0.1mi, but its much more unusual to see distances longer than 1000ft rendered in feet.

I've seen very few signs use yards, although I can't say if that's universal.

Comment: Based solely on my personal recollection as an American, I believe that feet are usually only used on smaller roads to serve as a warning about something upcoming that you should prepare for (usually a stop sign or light or other similar potential hazard).

Comment: You will see feet used by GPS devices (and Google Maps which is basically the same thing), but not for anything longer than 1000 ft.

Answer (score 4):

For walking distance I would use feet. If it was 100 feet away would you really want to say 0.02 miles?  On driving direction they say turn right in 100 feet.  Google maps detail does feet up to 1000 and then flops to miles.

Comment: Agreed: I'm used to seeing feet in units up to the hundreds.  Although a yard is close to a meter, yards are very rarely used, although there are certain areas in life where yards are used (perhaps most famously thunderblaster's example of American/Gridiron football).  Anything over 1,056 feet is over 0.2 miles so switching to miles may be good then.  If you can *also* show meters, you may help people be comfortable with both customary/imperial (miles) and metric (meters).  If you can't, just ditching the meters will be most comfortable for most Americans.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in the US, for measuring lengths and distances, people are more familiar with  "inch, foot, yard, and mile" and if you don't want your users to struggle through the app, then do use these units. But to provide a better UX you can provide an additional feature of changing the units as per the convenience by setting the local units as default.

Secondly, it depends on the time it takes to update the user's distance from the destination. Like if it is fast enough and with normal network connection it can update after every 10 yards lets say then go with the non-decimal part(176 yards instead of 0.1 mi) and if it is not dynamic or for some reasons it takes time to update the distance then go with the decimal part(0.1 mi instead of 176 yards).

Comment: As a lifelong US resident, I find measuring anything other than football field distances in yards odd.  I would expect most distances to be measured in either feet or miles.

Comment: @thunderblaster true, but they're still more commonly used than hands, links, rods, chains, furlongs, fathoms, cables, etc.

Comment: @DanNeely most people in the US do not know the US system very well. Standing in the kitchen I have had numerous women who have cooked all their lives ask me to convert pints to cups or quarts or whatever. Familiarity ("That's a cup!") does not translate to ability to manipulate measures. Tripling a recipe is right out.

Comment: @nocomprende the real killer for recipes is teaspoon vs tablespoon because its so easy for the clueless to corrupt them by assuming 't' vs 'T' is a purely aesthetic difference.  If you're not doing it everyday tripling should be idiot proof (stop laughing) without knowing any of the conversions or any math.  3x 1.5 cups is fill the 1 cup measure 3 times then fill the 1/2 cup measure 3 times.

Comment: @DanNeely OMG! Now I know why my coffee is sooo strong! You know, it gets me when they say that the US system is "approximate". An Inch is *exactly* 3 Barleycorns long. As in, Integer exact. Infinite precision. And, anyone can verify it. Take that, Metric System with your stupid Meter definition!

Comment: @nocomprende yup a standard Barley Corn is exactly 8.46666... mm long, just like a Standard Human Foot is 30.48 cm long; just like a Standard Earth has a circumference of 40,000,000 meters.

Comment: @DanNeely My foot is longer than most people's, but if you measure me with my own foot, I am normal height. See? It all just works out. Relativity!

Comment: @DanNeely You can imagine their confusion seeing 'Tsp' vs 'tbsp'.

Comment: @thunderblaster To quote *The Big Lebowski*: Clearly, you're not a golfer.

Comment: @DanNeely: and even in the UK I fear we're more likely now to say "cricket pitches" than "chains". Sic transit gloria mundi.

Comment: As an American, I use meters more than I use yards. Which is to say, since I'm not into football, I essentially never use yards in everyday life. If I wanted to refer to the distance of a yard, I would say 3 feet or a meter.

Answer (score 1):

Giving miles is better option but you can provide flexibility to the user

Like he can choose between km and miles for distance greater than 1 km and
yards/km/miles for shorter distance < 1 km

Comment: I think this the best option. Let the user decide. It isn't much extra trouble and it buries the issue forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is incremental, but I'd only reserve yards for walking distances, and only for numbers that can be easily rounded to a multiple of 100. An American football field is 100 yards long, so it's a familiar point of reference. And it's not uncommon to hear statements like "[wind turbine with blades two football fields long](https://www.mrosupply.com/page/wind-turbines-with-blades-two-football-fields-long/)".

Comment: As an American who isn't into football at all, I had no idea a football field is 100 yards long. I suppose that's worth remembering, but I'll probably forget it.

Comment: @Keavon so also remember that a non-American football field is 100 meters long. It all just works.